# Laravel update function throws exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently working with laravel and want to update 'Model' with a controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'criminal' => 'required|string',
        'crimes' => 'required|string',
        'happened_at' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|string',
        'report' => 'string|nullable',
        'happened_at' => 'required',
        'testifies' => 'string|nullable',
        'officers' => 'string|nullable',
    ]);

    $case               = Cases::find($id);
    $case->criminal     = $request->input('criminal');
    $case->crimes       = $request->input('crimes');
    $case->officers     = $request->input('officers');
    $case->testifies    = $request->input('testifies');
    $case->report       = $request->input('report');
    $case->happened_at  = $request->input('happened_at');
    $case->crime_desc   = $request->input('description');

    $case->save();
    return redirect('cases.index');
}
```

It does not save the data and throws an exception:`Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing`

Does somebody know why it throws an exception? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Stacktrace would indeed be helpfull.

Comment: sorry, im new to laravel, where i can find the stacktrace?

Comment: Can you add the `Cases` model?

Comment: `public function setHappenedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['happened_at'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i', $value);
}`

This is my Cases model

Comment: what is the format of happened at? Can you do dd($request->all()) and show us the output? Put if after validate. I would also recommend moving the validation logic in a request file and using $request->attribute directly instead of $request->input('attribute')

Comment: do you also have protected $dates=['happened_at']; in your model?

Comment: `array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "J8WiFWKiMfpitdWm8WCn0IyN5FfF3luS6PRdXFQY"
  "criminal" => "test1"
  "crimes" => "crimes"
  "officers" => "officers"
  "testifies" => "testifies"
  "happened_at" => "2018-03-29"
  "description" => "desc"
  "report" => "report"
  "_method" => "PUT"
]`

yes protected $dates['happened_at'] is in my model

Comment: also just noticed. Your model should be names at singular and you db table at plural. try using artisan to create models php artisan make:model Case if you need a migration as well php artisan make:model Case --migration

Comment: OK, here's your issue happended_at is Y-m-d in order for your code to work you need public function setHappenedAtAttribute($value) { $this->attributes['happened_at'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $value. '00:00'); } or don't make that column timestamp

Comment: what type is your field in the DB?

Comment: same name as in the attribute name in the script

Comment: type not name. as in is it timestamp/date/varchar etc

Comment: timestamp, but still does not work

Comment: writing my answer now

Comment: let me know if it worked for you

Comment: Yes it is working. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the request. Your field has this format Y-m-d while in the carbon setter you act as if the format is ('Y-m-d H:i:s')

I am not quite sure that the code even goes through that mutator (never used one with save)

```
This code should work:

$case               = Cases::find($id);
$case->criminal     = $request->input('criminal');
$case->crimes       = $request->input('crimes');
$case->officers     = $request->input('officers');
$case->testifies    = $request->input('testifies');
$case->report       = $request->input('report');
$case->happened_at  = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ' 00:00:01');
$case->crime_desc   = $request->input('description');
```

In this particular case I would recommend you actually having happened_at as a date instead of timestamp

If you use fillable in your model this code should also work

```
$request['happened_at'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ' 00:00:01');

Cases::find($id)->update($request->all());
```

If you have concerns about timezones save everything in UTC and then take advantage of unix timestamp

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormatUTC('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ' 00:00:01');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.
But is there a HTML Form Input Type for Laravel with Date + Time?

Comment: And so i need to change:`Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormatUTC('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ' 00:00:01');`
to
`Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormatUTC('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->happened_at. ':01');`
?

Comment: or just do Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormatUTC('Y-m-d H:i', $request->happened_at); see if it works if not then you're right

Comment: Hello again, there is a problem. it is not safing the day corretly its turing always to 1

Comment: that is related to your app timezone. Also make sure you have the latest version of Carbon

Comment: When using createFromFormatUTC when you show the data you need you need to set the local timezone back. $date->setTimezone('Europe/Berlin');

Answer (score 0):

$case->happened_at  = $request->input('happened_at'); is probably date field in DB - is data from form in correct format?

Set mutator for this:

```
public function setHappenedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['happened_at'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i', $value);
}
```

or without Carbon:

```
public function setHappenedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['happened_at'] = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($value));
}
```

eventually at the top of the model:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'happened_at'
];
```

Comment: actually  'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at', are already added by default so you would have protected $dates = [    'happened_at']; Check the Model class

Comment: and his issue is not with carbon, but with the request input. It's just date without time so this won't work

Comment: also deteled_at is only relevant when you use soft deletes.